# Javascript phone number validation: no regex evaluation

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a input field where the user is requested to fill his phone number without any sign, only numbers. Rules are:

- starts with 0 or 3;
- contains only numbers;
- length should be at least 9 and at most 15 digits;

I have written the following code:

```
    if ($('#tel').val()!='') {
        var numero=$('#tel').val();
        var n = numero.length;
        var inizio= numero.charAt(0);
        var phoneno = /^\d{9,15}$/;
        if (((inizio!='3')&&(inizio!='0'))&&( !phoneno.test(numero))) {
            alert('Il numero di telefono inserito non \u00E8 valido');
            $('#tel').focus();
            error =error+1;
        }
    }
```

Works fine but doesn't filter for letters inside the number. What's wrong with that?
It seems it doesn't go through the test at all!

Comment: replace `&&` with `||` in your code. it's a logical issue, not regex.

Comment: Is this for an event handler or final validation?

Comment: It's for a form where i collect some contact details from those users who want further information. Phone is the preferred contact method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use **OR** instead of **AND** for your expression:

```
if (inizio!='3' || inizio!='0' || !phoneno.test(numero)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to replace your code:

```
var phoneno = /^[03]\d{8,14}$/

if ( !phoneno.test(numero) ) {
        alert('Il numero di telefono inserito non \u00E8 valido');
        $('#tel').focus();
        error = error+1;
}
```

Comment: Yep! The title is misleading. The right one should be no regex performed. My original code seemed to skip the regex. The reason is the and instead of or in the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to want a no-regex solution ("no regex evaluation" written in title), here's one that doesn't use a regular expression.

```
function isValidPhone(phone) {
    var firstChar = phone[0];

    if (typeof phone !== 'string' || 
       (phone.length < 9 || phone.length > 15) ||
       !(firstChar === '0' || firstChar === '3')) return false;

    return [].every.call(phone, function (char) { return !isNaN(+char); });
}
```

You can use it like:

```
var tel = $('#tel').val();

if (tel && !isValidPhone(tel)) {
    //invalid phone
}
```